How to delete a datapoint from vector search index in GCP?
How to delete a datapoint from vector search index in GCP?
I read that it can be done using the update_embedding method
image
But couldn't figure out how to do it. Can someone help me with the same?
I tried updating the index by providing a json file that had empty entries for the embedding ids to be deleted, but it threw an error

You will have to create an index with update method as STREAM_UPDATE and then you can upsert or remove datapoints.
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/vector-search/update-rebuild-index#upsert-streaming
https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform.MatchingEngineIndex#google_cloud_aiplatform_MatchingEngineIndex_upsert_datapoints
